# Tomcat docker container logs hangs after few hours

Tags: docker, spring-mvc, web-applications, tomcat9

I am using tomcat:9.0-jre8-alpine image to deploy my application. when i run the below command it works perfectly and displays logs.

```
docker logs -f <containername>
```

but after a few hours logs gets struck and whatever the operation we do on the application it does not display new logs. Container is running as expected and there is enough ram and disk space on the VM.

Note: I run the same container on 3 different VMs. Only 1 VM has this problem.

How can I debug/resolve the issue?

Answer (score 1):

1. check you docker version, is it too old that you may meet 
   https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/35332 It's a dead lock caused by github.com/fsnotify/fsnotify pkg. fsnotify PR
2. check the daemon config in /etc/docker/daemon.json for docker log configuration.
   and you need to check container configuration with `docker inspect` to see the log options.

Sometimes I try to look into the /var/lib/docker/containers/Container-ID/Container-ID.json to see the log if you use json-file log format.

If you use journald, you may find the log in /var/log/messages

Comment: Thanks @paco alcaler. Upgrading to latest docker version might be the last step I will try because it is a production machine. There is no daemon.json on my centos6 machine. I tried to look at container-id.json. But it is also not getting updated with latest logs.